# Data to be stored in array at particular index

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have 8 grid boxes where these 8 boxes have 4 properties

```
id, name, age, location
```

id is **editable** while others are **readonly** data with Textfield so that I can set values based on id selected.

Now `onChange` event will pass two parameters `(event,index)`

For example :

**grid box 1:** `event, "0"`
**grid box 2:** `event, "1"`
**grid box 3:** `event, "2"`
......
......

So, I am **hardcording** the index and I have array type state variable

```
this.state={
 personData:[]
}

 handlePersonId = (event, index) =>{

      const { personData } = this.state;

      personData.push({id:'', name:'', age:'', location:''});
      personData[index].id=event.target.value;
      this.setState(this.state.personData);
    }
```

If I go and inserting data with sequence it is working fine but when I enter id for grid box 2,3,4,...8 then I get error since I am pushing attribute sequentially not at index not at particular index therefore I am getting **undefined**.

**Expected output:** If I have entered in grid box 5 therefore passing index **4** with event target value as **23**

> [{},{},{},{},{id:'23', name:'Omkar', age:'22', location:'usa'}]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to:

- update the `id` of existing "person" items in the `personData` array based on data in the `event` object
- create a new "person" at `index` in `personData` if it does not exist
- ensure that items in the `personData` array (prior to `index`) are at least initialised as empty objects, once the `handlePersonId()` function is called

To achieve that, you could implement `handlePersonId()` as shown/documented below:

```
handlePersonId = (event, index) =>{

    this.setState(({ personData }) => {

        /* Extract id from event */
        const id = event.target.value;

        /* Clone person array */
        const cloneArray = [].concat(personData);

        /* Iterate index range from 0 to check for invalid person 
        entries and add an empty object if required */
        for(let i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            cloneArray[i] = cloneArray[i] || {};
        }

        if(cloneArray[index]) {
            /* Update id of person at index if person data already 
            exists */
            cloneArray[index].id = id;
        }
        else {
            /* Otherwise create a new person object at index */
            cloneArray[index] = {
                id, 
                name:'', 
                age:'', 
                location:''
            } 
        }

        /* Return new state */
        return { personData : cloneArray };    
    });
}
```